# Fast insert into table with Foreign Key constraints

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have to periodically insert data into table #1 that contains foreign key reference to table #2. And table #2 is quite big - about 200.000 rows. I'm trying to check rows that must be inserted into table #1 for foreign key constraint by simply removing those rows that definitely can't be inserted, and my query looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM temp_table1
WHERE temp_table1.fk NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2) AND
temp_table1.id_d IS NOT NULL;
```

The problem is, this method is veeery slow :( So is there any "right" method to insert rows in such situation?

I'm using Python3, Postgresql and Psycopg2, if it matters.

Comment: `... if it matters.` No, that shouldn't matter. What *does* matter is: your table definitions, including keys&indexes.

Comment: @wildplasser Ok, table1 has field "fk" that references primary key "id" from table2, and table2 also has index on "id" field.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `delete` step. `insert` directly in instead:

```
insert into table1
select t1.*
from 
    temp_table1 t1
    inner join
    table2 t2 on t1.fk = t2.id
where t1.id_d is not null
```